# Unique php string generation

Tags: php

I am using

```
uniqid(md5(time(),false)).uniqid(md5(rand(),false));
```

to generate unique string. Is this safe to use or there is a chance of collisions? What would you recommend me to use?

Comment: This post does not show *any* research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

md5 with time will generate a new unique id evert time but as you are randomizing this generate value there is some chances of collision Instead you can do it like below function

```
function newId() { return uniqid() . '_' . md5(mt_rand()); }
```

It will generate a uniqueid and append md5 random value to it so it will always be unique and will be very deficult to brutforce this.